# Rewrite rule to apply variable to every page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a site that has 4 folders.  Let's say:

*example.com/projects/folder1/

example.com/projects/folder2/

example.com/projects/folder3/

example.com/projects/folder4/*

Each folder contains subfolders and files, etc... They're basically clones of each other but they all pull data from a different database name.

What I'd like to do is merge these all into a single folder so when something changes I only have to edit 1 file instead of 4.

*example.com/projects*

then use the url to specify which database it should fetch the data from:

*example.com/projects/database1/*

So far, I've been able to make this work with the homepage with the following ReWrite Rule:

*RewriteRule  ^projects/([a-z]+)/?$   /projects/index.php?db=$1    [NC,L]    # Homepage*

But if I try any link under it, say example.com/projects/database1/somefolder/somefile.php?id=1&aa=bb, I get a 404 error.

Is it possible to accomplish what I want to do without having to specify individual rewrite rules for every sub-folder/file?

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your rule does not work for files deeping down the path is that your pattern does not match anything expect paths that consist of only letters:

> RewriteRule ^projects/([a-z]+)/?$ /projects/index.php?db=$1 [NC,L] # Homepage

In there the `([a-z]+)` matches exactly that: all letters from "a" to "z", case insensitive. You'd have to change that to something that captures the name of that folder up to a terminating slash or the end pf the requested path:

```
RewriteRule ^/?projects/([^/]+) /projects/index.php?db=$1 [NC,L] # Homepage
```

However there is a much simpler approach that does not even require such a "variable". You don't have to extract that information on this level. That is the classical router approach:

```
RewriteRule ^/?projects/ /projects/index.php [L]
```

Your index script has access to the requested path via the "superglobal" variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. And it is *much* more comfortable to handle such tasks inside php. So not on protocol level but inside your application logic. In there you can simply do something like that:

```
if (preg_match('|/projects/([^/]+)|i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $token)) {
    $db = $token[1];
} else {
    throw new Exception("undefined database definition");
}
echo "Using database connnection '$db' ...";
```

`$db` will then contain the desired folder name even without that variable you specified on protocol level. And this obviously allows for a much more complex logic when required.